# ExpandableListView Third Level Error: Second Child auto close when First Group expand or collapse

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I'm using `ExpandableListView` to create a menu third level

First, I expand a **First Group** display the **Second Child**

Next, I expand **Second Child** display the **Third Child**

But, when I expand or collapse different **First Group** then **Second Child** auto collapse.

What's happen?

Please help me.

CategoryAdapter.class

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter{

    private Context context;
    private List<ChildData> dataList;
    IActionCLickListener itemActionListener;


    public CategoryAdapter(Context context, List<ChildData> dataList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.dataList = dataList;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int arg0, int arg1) {
        return arg1;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        CustomExpandableListView secondLevelELV = new CustomExpandableListView(context);
        SubCategoryAdapter adapter = new SubCategoryAdapter(context,
                dataList.get(groupPosition).getChildrenData(),
                itemActionListener,
                dataList.get(groupPosition).getName());
        secondLevelELV.setAdapter(adapter);
        secondLevelELV.setGroupIndicator(null);
        secondLevelELV.setDivider(secondLevelELV.getResources().getDrawable(R.color.transparent));
        secondLevelELV.setChildDivider(secondLevelELV.getResources().getDrawable(R.color.transparent));
        ExpandableListView expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) parent;
        ChildData item = dataList.get(groupPosition);
        


        return secondLevelELV;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {

        return this.dataList.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return dataList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_category_expanble_list, null);

            LinearLayout llCategory = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.llCategory);
            TextView tvCategory = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvCategory);
            ImageView img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img);

            tvCategory.setText(dataList.get(groupPosition).getName());
            ExpandableListView expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) parent;
            if (dataList.get(groupPosition).getChildrenData().isEmpty()) {
                img.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }else {
                img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                if (isExpanded) {
                    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.expandable_group_up);
                } else {
                    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.expandable_group_down);
                }
            }

            if (dataList.get(groupPosition).getChildrenData().isEmpty()){
                llCategory.setOnClickListener(view -> itemActionListener.onClickedItem(dataList.get(groupPosition)));
            }



        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }



    public void setItemActionListener(IActionCLickListener itemActionListener) {
        this.itemActionListener = itemActionListener;
    }
}
```

SubCategoryAdapter.class

```
public class SubCategoryAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    List<ChildData_> childrenData;
    IActionCLickListener iActionCLickListener;
    String name;


    public SubCategoryAdapter(Context context, List<ChildData_> childrenData, IActionCLickListener iActionCLickListener, String name) {
        this.context = context;
        this.childrenData = childrenData;
        this.iActionCLickListener = iActionCLickListener;
        this.name = name;

    }

    public void setiActionCLickListener(IActionCLickListener iActionCLickListener) {
        this.iActionCLickListener = iActionCLickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return childrenData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_sub_category_expanble_list, null);

        LinearLayout llSubCategory = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.llSubCategory);
        TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSubCategory);
        ImageView img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        ExpandableListView expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) parent;
        text.setText(childrenData.get(groupPosition).getName());
        if (childrenData.get(groupPosition).getChildrenData().isEmpty()) {
            img.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }else if (childrenData.get(groupPosition).getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Search by featured")){
            if (isExpanded) {
                img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.expandable_group_up);

            } else {
                img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.expandable_group_down);

            }

        }else {
            img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

        if (childrenData.get(groupPosition).getChildrenData().isEmpty()){
            llSubCategory.setOnClickListener(view -> iActionCLickListener.onClickedSubItem(name,childrenData.get(groupPosition)));

        }

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_sub_category_expandable_list1, null);

        LinearLayout llSubCategory = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.llSubCategory);
        TextView tvSubCategory = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSubCategory);
        tvSubCategory.setText(childrenData.get(groupPosition).getChildrenData().get(childPosition).getName());
        ChildData_ item = childrenData.get(groupPosition);
        ExpandableListView expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) parent;

        if (iActionCLickListener != null){
            llSubCategory.setOnClickListener(view -> iActionCLickListener.onClickedSubItem_(name, childrenData.get(groupPosition).getChildrenData().get(childPosition)));

        }

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return childrenData.get(groupPosition).getChildrenData().size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

CustomExpandableListView.class

```
public class CustomExpandableListView extends ExpandableListView {

    public CustomExpandableListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }



    public CustomExpandableListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomExpandableListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        int heightMeasureSpec_custom = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec_custom);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
        params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
    }
}
```

```
public interface IActionCLickListener{

    void onClickedItem(ChildData item);

    void onClickedSubItem(String name, ChildData_ item);

    void onClickedSubItem_(String name, ChildData item);
}
```

**Illustration**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHy4M.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qu4ic.png)